# How to select single control in UITableView in iOS ipad aap?

Tags: ios5, uitableview, uisplitview

I'm very new to iOS development. I have created an split view project using project wizard for my ipad application.Now the problem that i'm facing is that, i want to add three buttons in a cell and want them to tap individually. When i run i run the project and try to tap the button the whole row goes selected instead of a single button. How to prevent that.. Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have used

```
 [cell.backgroundView addSubview:yourButton];
```

use

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:yourButton];
```